# How to access React child components using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I just started exploring Jest and Enzyme in React, and was trying to access the props of a child component. The test case:

```
describe('<Component_A/>', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Component_A/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
    it('should render Component_A', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(Component_A)).toHaveLength(0);
    });
});
```

Component_A:

```
const component_A = (props) => {

return (<Component_B
        items={items}
    />);
}
```

I tried .find(), .get(0), checked the wrapper's props, children, there was no reference of Component_B.

Can anyone please explain how we can access **Component_B** and it's props **items** in test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "mount" instead of "shallow".

Also add displayName to Component_A in order to find it by name.

```
Component_A.displayName = "Component_A";
```